# Why is the database result inside this woocommerce hook returning null on COD orders?

Tags: mysql, woocommerce, metadata, hook

We collect some non-product related information from our customers during the order process and store it in a database table. We then pull that data back out of the database and add it to the Admin New Order Email, which looks like this:

```
Location: Hospital
County:   Los Angeles
Delivery: Pickup
```

This is the hook we use:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'add_email_order_meta', 10, 3 );

function add_email_order_meta( $order_obj, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ){
    global $wpdb;
    $order_id = $order_obj->get_order_number();

    $result = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM cl_order_meta 
              WHERE order_id = " . $order_id, OBJECT );

    if ($sent_to_admin) {
        echo '
        <ul>
        <li><strong>Location:</strong> ' . $result->location. '</li>
        <li><strong>County:</strong> ' . $result->county. '</li>
        <li><strong>Delivery:</strong> ' . $result->delivery. '</li>
        </ul>';
    } 
}
```

This works great on credit card orders but Cash on Delivery orders result in no data like this:

```
Location:
County:  
Delivery:
```

I have confirmed the data is in the database and it is all there. I receive the email with no metadata. If I echo out the Order ID in the email it is correct. If I echo out json_encode($result) it is NULL, so it is like the query isn't returning anything. I tried putting a sleep(5) before the query, thinking maybe the database was still writing, but that didn't help.

What could be causing this on COD orders only?

I know the hook is firing because the email has the labels and the Order ID, but the data from the query is not there.

I do see this in my Apache error logs, but I am not sure how it is related:

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: The WC_Product::get_parent function is deprecated 
since version 3.0. Replace with WC_Product::get_parent_id.PHP message: The 
WC_Product::get_post_data function is deprecated since version 3.0. Replace with 
get_post.

PHP message: The WC_Product::get_post_data function is deprecated since version 3.0. 
Replace with get_post.

PHP message: The WC_Product::get_parent function is deprecated since version 3.0. 
Replace with WC_Product::get_parent_id.

PHP message: The WC_Product::get_post_data function is deprecated since version 3.0. 
Replace with get_post.

PHP message: The WC_Product::get_parent function is deprecated since version 3.0. 
Replace with WC_Product::get_parent_id.

PHP message: The WC_Product::get_post_data function is deprecated since version 3.0. 
Replace with get_post.

PHP message: woocommerce_add_order_item_meta is deprecated since version 3.0.0! Use 
woocommerce_new_order_item instead.

PHP message: woocommerce_add_order_item_meta is deprecated since version 3.0.0! Use 
woocommerce_new_order_item instead.

PHP message: woocommerce_add_order_item_meta is deprecated since version 3.0.0! Use 
woocommerce_new_order_item instead.

PHP message: woocommerce_add_order_item_meta is deprecated since version 3.0.0! Use 
woocommerce_new_order_item instead.

PHP message: woocommerce_add_order_item_meta is deprecated since version 3.0.0! Use 
woocommerce_new_order_item instead.', referer: https://example.com/checkout/
```

Database Insert

```
add_action('wp_ajax_cl_add_session_vars_to_db', 
'add_session_vars_to_db');

function add_session_vars_to_db() {
    global $wpdb;

    $order_id = $_POST['order_id'];
    $wpdb->insert('cl_order_meta', 
        array(
          'order_id' => $order_id,
          'location' => isset($_SESSION['location']) ? $_SESSION['location'] : 'N/A',
          'county => isset($_SESSION['county']) ? $_SESSION['county'] : 'N/A',
          'delivery' => isset($_SESSION['delivery']) ? $_SESSION['delivery'] : 'Pickup',
          'create_date' => time()
));
```

}

Comment: Could you share the code where you save the data upon order submit?

Comment: I've added it at the bottom but i don't see why that matters. The data is always in the database and is correct. That isn't the problem.

Comment: Is there a different hook for COD order receipts? The labels are thee though just not the data.

Comment: Just a note - 'county is missing a closing quote. In regard to the overall issue, this requires a full troubleshooting analysis, it could be anything and anywhere - the code you shared is not sufficient to understand where the problem is unfortunately

Comment: So I figured out that the database insert is happening too late. Do you know the earliest place (time and file) wherwe i can grab the new order ID and insert the data?

Comment: In fact, this was my guess as well. Your wp_ajax_cl_add_session_vars_to_db hook is what needs more context, that's why I said the code you shared is not sufficient. If the data is entered at checkout, try use woocommerce_payment_complete hook to save the data